# Как сделать css анимацию для списков меню при наведении?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation, stylus

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой код:

```
<ul className="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
    <li>
        <a className="dropdown button" href="#">1</a>
        <a  href="#">1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Эффект для анимации при наведении на stylus

```
li a:first-child
  background-color #ff8731
  background-size 100% 200%
  background-image linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff8731 50%, #fff 50%)
  transition background-position 0.3s

li a:last-child
  background-color #fff
  background-size 100% 200%
  background-image linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #ff8731 50%)
  border-top 1px solid #fff
  border-top-left-radius 0
  border-top-right-radius 0
  color #0073AE
  display none
  margin-top -10px
  transition background-position 0.3s

li a:last-child:hover
  background-position 0 -100%
  color #fff
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб при наведении на `a:last-child` у `a:first-child` запускалась такая же анимация, как и у `a:last-child`?

Answer (score 1):

Никак.
CSS может влиять на стили вложенных элементов и элементов, находящихся после элемента инициатора, при помощи оператора

```
.style1 + .style2 {
  background: red;
}

<div class='style1'></div>
<div class='style2'></div> //будет красный


<div class='style1'></div>
<div></div>
<div class='style2'></div> //не будет красный
```

тут пример того, как можно получить, **почти** то, что тебе надо:
(Наводи на первый элемент)
http://plnkr.co/edit/ewIBeWXiQnPbuqyOACvu?p=preview

---

*Как вариант, можно при наведении на родителя добавлять стили первому и последнему элементу, но я думаю ты уже об этом думал...*